# Nested divs won't create a box inside a box?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a section that spans 50% of the page. Within that section I would like to place a box of text containing two lines which will lineup with the bullet points on the list to the righthand side. Why is it not putting the box inside the main section if I nested the divs?

```
<div class="content">
        <h2>Brigham Young University</h2>
        <h3><span>Computer Engineering, Minor in Computer Science</span></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>3.36 GPA</li>
            <li>4.0 STEM GPA</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="grad_date">
            <p>Provo, UT <br>
                Expected 2018</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Css:

```
.content {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 50%;
}

.content #grad_date {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it isn't putting the box inside the main section? The problem I see is that you hardcoded the grad_date and the .content is relatively sized so this would make the grad_date to be bigger than the box potentially..

Comment: My CSS as you can see isn't great, in the grand scheme of the web page I basically have a 50/50 split with an image on the right and this chunk of text. I need that red box to be inside the block box and to the right so that I can align the text with the bullet points if that makes sense. Would it help if I posted the entire html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.content`:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvrycsu2/)

Comment: drweck08 to the rescue again! That put it in the same box, not I've just got to get it to line up. Should I float the list as well as the red box?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display rule for the unordered list to `inline-block`.

Also make sure to clear the float by adding `overflow: hidden` to the `.container` div. Which is one way to do it.

```css
.content {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content #grad_date {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2>Brigham Young University</h2>
  <h3><span>Computer Engineering, Minor in Computer Science</span></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>3.36 GPA</li>
    <li>4.0 STEM GPA</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="grad_date">
    <p>Provo, UT <br />
      Expected 2018</p>
  </div>
</div>
```